# Python multiprocessing - how to make it more efficient

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Consider the following two short programs.

**normal_test.py**:

```
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t_end = time.time() + 1
    loop_iterations = 0
    while time.time() < t_end:
        loop_iterations += 1

    print(loop_iterations)
```

**Output** (on my machine):

```
4900677
```

**mp_test.py**:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Manager
import time


def loop1(ns):
    t_end = time.time() + 1
    while time.time() < t_end:
        ns.loop_iterations1 += 1


def loop2(ns):
    t_end = time.time() + 1
    while time.time() < t_end:
        ns.loop_iterations2 += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    ns = manager.Namespace()
    ns.loop_iterations1 = 0
    ns.loop_iterations2 = 0

    p1 = Process(target=loop1, args=(ns,))
    p2 = Process(target=loop2, args=(ns,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print(ns.loop_iterations1)
    print(ns.loop_iterations2)
```

**Output** (on my machine):

```
5533
5527
```

I am hoping to use Python multiprocessing on a Raspberry Pi to read values from multiple ADCs in parallel. As such, speed is important. The laptop I ran these two programs on has four cores, so I can't understand why the processes created in the second program are only able to run nearly 900 times less iterations than the single process in the first program. Am I using the Python multiprocessing library incorrectly? How can I make the processes faster?

Comment: Replacing the namespace with two `num1 = Value('d', 0.0)` improves it but still slower. The problem probably is the overhead of managing the shared state

Comment: #H4kor Yeah, unfortunately I need the shared state because I have flags that both processes need access to. I might need to rethink my design then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I using the Python multiprocessing library incorrectly?

Incorrectly?  No.  Inefficiently?  Yes.

Remember that multiprocessing creates cooperative, but otherwise independent, instances of Python.  Think of them as workers in a factory, or friends working on a big job.

If only *one* person is working on a project, that one person is free to move about the factory floor, pick up a tool, use it, put it down, move somewhere else, pick up the next tool, and so on.  Add a second person—or worse, more people, perhaps even hundreds of people—and the person must now coordinate: if some area is shared, or some tool is shared, Bob can't just go grab something, he has to ask Alice first if she's done with it.

A `Manager` object is Python multiprocessing's general wrapper for sharing.  Putting variables in a Manager `Namespace` means *these are shared, so automatically check with everyone else before you use them*.  (More precisely, they're held in one location—one process—and accessed or changed from others via proxies.)

Here, you have done the metaphorical equivalent of replacing "Bob: count as fast as you can" with "Bob: constantly interrupt Alice to ask if she's counting, then count; Alice: count, but be constantly interrupted by Bob."  Bob and Alice are now spending most, by far, of their time talking to each other, rather than counting.

As [the documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes):

> ... when doing concurrent programming it is usually best to avoid using shared state as far as possible. This is particularly true when using multiple processes.

(it starts with the phrase "as mentioned above" but it's not mentioned above!).

There are a bunch of standard tricks, such as *batching* to get a lot of work done *between* sharing events, or using *shared memory* to speed up the sharing—but with shared memory you introduce the need to *lock* items.

Comment: I understand that shared state isn't needed in the program in my question, but in my actual code, I have global flags that both processes need access to.

Comment: If they only need *read* access, make copies. If they need *read and write* access, consider copies-and-batching: e.g., generate 1000 results on the assumption that the flags have not changed. Then, if the flags changed, throw away that work and start over with new flags.

Comment: what is the difference between shared memory and a shared state / variable in the manager namespace?

Comment: @bgenchel: shared memory is literally that: different processes or threads write to the same memory, without any work required elsewhere. This has pluses (fast) and minus (need to coordinate). A managed variable in Python means that read and write of the variable go through Python code, which can arrange to do sharing. This has pluses (it just works, someone else did all the hard parts) and minuses (it's very slow).

Comment: @torek can you comment on my answer below? Thx.

Comment: @arun: the point of `multiprocessing.Queue` is to avoid using shared memory to communicate in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a better way to implement parallel processing (when shared state is not needed) is with multiprocessing `Queue`. The OP's two loops don't need a shared state.

Here are the tests.

Specs:

- Python version: 3.7.6.
- Machine has two Intel i-9 9880H CPUs at 2.3 GHz.

When I executed `normal_test.py` in the question, I got:

```
$ python normal_test.py
7601322
```

Then I tested multiprocessing `Queue` as follows (two parallel processes):

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


def loop(n, q):
    n_iter = 0
    t_end = time.time() + 1
    while time.time() < t_end:
        n_iter += 1
    q.put((n, n_iter))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = []

    q = Queue()
    procs = []
    for i in range(2):
        procs.append(Process(target=loop, args=(i, q)))

    for proc in procs:
        proc.start()

    for proc in procs:
        n, loop_count = q.get()
        results.append((n, loop_count))

    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()

    del procs, q

    for r in results:
        print(r)
```

When I executed this, I got:

```
$ python multiproc2.py
(1, 10570043)
(0, 10580648)
```

It looks like running two processes in parallel is able to do more work than running just one.

Comment: `multiprocessing.Queue` handles communication, without relying on the user to do it through shared memory. This gets you correctness with (relatively) easy programming, sometimes at the cost of performance. If the performance of `Queue` is not an issue, that may very well be the way to go. It's a lot easier to get right.